# How do I use the :source parameter on has_many :through associations with models that are namespaced?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Here are the models.

`Recipes::Recipe`:

```
module Recipes
  class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ApplicationHelper

    attr_accessible :body, :title, :author, :photos, :tags

    has_many :photos
    has_many :favorites
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :tags, :through => :taggings

    belongs_to :author,
               :class_name => :User,
               :foreign_key => :author_id

    has_many :favorers,
             :source => :user,
             :through => :favorites

    before_create :default_values
    before_validation :create_slug

    validates_presence_of :title, :body, :author
    validates_uniqueness_of :title, :slug
  end
end
```

`User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :recipes,
           :class_name => 'Recipes::Recipe',
           :foreign_key => :author_id

  has_many :favorite_recipes,
           :class_name => 'Recipes::Recipe',
           :foreign_key => :recipe_id,
           :source => :recipe,
           :through => :favorites

  end
end
```

`Recipes::Favorite`:

```
module Recipes
  class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :user_id, :recipe_id

    belongs_to :recipe,
               :class_name => "Recipes::Recipe"
    belongs_to :user,
               :class_name => "User"
  end
end
```

The association works when referencing attributes on the `Recipes::Recipe` model. If I do `recipe = Recipes::Recipe.first; recipe.favorers` it works. When I do `user = User.first; user.favorite_recipes` I receive an error.

The error:

```
1.9.3-p392 :002 > u.favorite_recipes
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association     
:favorites in model User
```

I assume it's trying to find the model `Favorite`, but really it should be `Recipes::Favorite`. I read in the Rails documentation that `:foreign_key` and `:class_name` are ignored on `has_many :through` associations, but I tried them anyway, and it still didn't work. So now I'm wondering, how can I tell a `has_many :through`'s `:source` parameter that it should look for a namespaced model? I have also tried `:recipes_recipe` for the `:source` parameter, and the table name for `:favorites` is just 'favorites'.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem.

The solution was in the error.

`ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association

:favorites in model User`

The `has_many :through` association was looking for a `has_many :favorites` on the `User` model.

So, I just added `has_many :favorites, :class_name => 'Recipes::Favorite'` and the above code began working for both associations.

Comment: Nice one mate, this one solved it for me. Thx for updating with your solution!

Comment: @zeromodulus You can always accept your own answer.